# good algo to flip css properties from left <-> right

Tags: css

Is it safe to assume that all properties that end with "left" have a corresponding "right" and vice versa and flipping them the other way is sufficient ? Naturally one would also need to flip values with left and right. Have i missed anything ?

EDIT
Yes i would like to be create an horizontal flipped stylesheet for RTL and LTR etc.

imagine a simple contrived stylesheet

```
#something {
   border-left: 2px;
   border-right: 5px;
   border-top: 12px;
}
```

h flipped becomes

```
#something {
   border-right: 2px;
   border-left: 5px;
   border-top: 12px;
}
```

Comment: By flipping values what do you mean?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Displaying a right-hand border when CSS specifies left, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Not all left and right properties end in `-left` or `-right`.

For instance, you have `border-left-color` and `border-right-color`, so you'll need to do more than just check for "ending in -left or ending in -right".

You might also want to take a look Mozilla's [RTL Locales](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Making_Sure_Your_Theme_Works_with_RTL_Locales) pages. Interesting read.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the exceptions to the left/right detection. Your point that components of the name might be the left/right token that needs swapping is well noted. Thanks for the moz link.

Comment: ive also observed that some properties need to have their values flipped, eg float: left/right etc.